# WP7: Get userinput into a running thread (BackgroundWorker)

Tags: windows-phone-7, synchronization, backgroundworker

currently i'm developing a WP7 that contacts a RemoteService within a BackgroundWorker. As Part of the communication the user needs to validate some Data (something like captcha). As the Communication is connection session based and synchronous i can not complete the background worker, ask the user and start a new communication to the server.

So the question is, is there any way to pause the BackgroundWorker, ask the User for input, pass that input into the BackgroundWorker and unpause the WorkerThread?

Thanks and kind Regards

Kornelis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the MVVMLight Dialog message as described [here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/209338?ProjectName=mvvmlight) to send a message to the View to ask it to prompt the user for a message.

In order to pause/unpause the background worker, you could wait on an [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=VS.96).aspx) in your background thread, and in the dialog's callback, signal the event to let the background worker know that the response has come back ...